# Hexo.io Error YAMLException: duplicated mapping key

Tags: node.js, hexo

I am getting the following error on any hexo command (clean / deploy / generate) and I'm completely stumped. There is no mention of the file that has the duplicated mapping key... FWIW, I'm on Mac OS X. I did a grep for "type: git" (grep -rnil "type: git" * /*) but the line and column are not correct.

I am not a node.js master, but I'm struggling to find out next steps.

```
FATAL duplicated mapping key at line 86, column 3:
      type: git
      ^
YAMLException: duplicated mapping key at line 86, column 3:
      type: git
      ^
    at generateError (/usr/home/test/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:165:10)
    at throwError (/usr/home/test/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:171:9)
    at storeMappingPair (/usr/home/test/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:308:7)
    at readBlockMapping (/usr/home/test/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1071:9)
    at composeNode (/usr/home/test/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1332:12)
    at readBlockMapping (/usr/home/test/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1062:11)
    at composeNode (/usr/home/test/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1332:12)
    at readDocument (/usr/home/test/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1492:3)
    at loadDocuments (/usr/home/test/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1548:5)
    at Object.load (/usr/home/test/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1569:19)
    at Hexo.yamlHelper (/usr/home/test/node_modules/hexo/lib/plugins/renderer/yaml.js:7:15)
    at Hexo.tryCatcher (/usr/home/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Hexo.<anonymous> (/usr/home/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:15:34)
    at Promise.then.text (/usr/home/test/node_modules/hexo/lib/hexo/render.js:61:21)
    at tryCatcher (/usr/home/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/home/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/home/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/home/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/home/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:694:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/usr/home/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/usr/home/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/usr/home/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
```

Comment: Where is the input that generates this error? And of course searching for the key **and** value makes little sense, as the error indicates you have a key (`type`) that appears multiple times, it says nothing about the value being duplicated as well.

Comment: @Anthon, the input is stated in the first sentence of the question. Any hexo command, such as `hexo clean` or `hexo generate` or `hexo deploy`. I did grep for 'git' which returned two files, neither of which had 'type: git' and for 'type', but that produced 100s of hits...

Answer (score -1):

You should following :
**- type: git**
repo:
branch: master
**- type: git**
repo:
branch: master
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeUVM.png)